# Parse substring in email data

Tags: python, regex, findall

```py
data = " #33986=\r\n6 for User ID: 125091. "
```

Above is what I have split down from an email, the data I need is from it is only this:  `339866`

The data is dynamic meaning the email sent to us is from a human so we have to parse it and catch the data. Things about the data that distinguishes it from other:

Starts with a `3` and is always `6` characters long.
What can I do to convert this into code to parse and find it?

What is the best way to clean the substring from the HTML and random letters to only get the numbers and ignore the second set of numbers?

I have do the following:

```py
data = re.findall("\d+", data)
```

Response is:

```
['33986', '6', '125091']
```

It's a very ugly response, is there a cleaner method?

Comment: Returning the first value is an option: `data = re.findall("\d+", data)[0]`

Comment: `data = re.findall(r'3\d{5}', data)[0]`

Comment: The problem with `r'3\d{5}'` is that if the first string starting with 3 is more than 6 digits, then it will pick that as well. You want to pick only the string that has 6 digits

Comment: Try this. It will fix your problem. `d = ''.join(re.findall("\d+", data))[:6]`

Answer (score 1):

```
data = " #33986=\r\n6 for User ID: 125091. "
x = re.search(r"(3\d\d\d\d)\S\s\s(\d)", data)
data = x.group(1) + x.group(2)
```

This will print the data you need, use `int(data)` if you need the final data to be an integer

Comment: I also need data[1]

Comment: @n9pe check latest changes

Comment: wouldn't this just pull all the numbers. OP was looking specifically for a number that starts with 3 and is 6 chars in length.

Comment: Finally found the best solution - check above

Comment: wouldn't this be simpler? `d = ''.join(re.findall("\d+", data))[:6]`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

You could filter the remaining data for the conditions you need.

Mind that your string is only 5 digits long.

```
data = ['33986', '6', '125091'] 
  
for s in data:
   if len(s)==5 and s[0]=="3":
      print("This is the solution: "+s)
```

Comment: This worked but my final data needs the 6 in the middle also '33986', '6',    final result = 339866

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest way to get what you want would be to add a join statement and trim the string to first 6 digits only. You can do it as follows.

```
data = " #33986=\r\n6 for User ID: 125091. "
d = ''.join(re.findall("\d+", data))[:6]
print (d)
```

You can get the first sequence of 6 digits that start with 3 using the below code.

```
x = re.findall(r"\D(3\d{5})\D", " "+s+" ")[0]
```

If you want to get all of them, then you can skip the `[0]`. It will give you a list of values. Remember it will still pick only the numbers that start with 3 and has 6 digits. If you want all the numbers, then use the below code.

```
x = re.findall("\d+", s)
```

If you want to concatenate all of them into a single number, then you can do the following.

```
''.join(re.findall("\d+", s))
```

If you want to concatenate only the the first 2 elements of the regEx, then you can use

```
''.join(re.findall("\d+", s)[:2])
```

Here's what I got with the below code:

```
data = " #33986=\r\n6 for User ID: 125091. "

#to get the first 2 digits, use this regex
x = ''.join(re.findall("\d+", data)[:2])
print (x)

#if you want all the numbers, then you can use this code
y = ''.join(re.findall("\d+", data))
print (y)
```

Output:

```
339866
339866125091
```

Comment: n9pe only needs 339866

Comment: @Hedy, thanks. yes, my code provides all the options for n9pe. While we need to provide the required answer,  we should also provide additional information that can benefit the OP for further expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Might be not the optimized solution. But will solve your case.

```
import re
data = " #33986=\r\n6 for User ID: 125091. "
data = re.findall("\d+", data)
final_result = ""
fixed_length = 6
for element in data:
    if final_result:
        if fixed_length - len(final_result) > len(element):
            final_result += element[0:fixed_length - len(final_result)]
        else:
            final_result += element
        
    if not final_result and element[0] == '3' and len(element) > 6:
        final_result += element[0:6]
        break
    
    if not final_result and element[0] == '3' and len(element) < 6:
        final_result += element
    if len(final_result) == 6:
        break
print(final_result)
```

Output:-339866

Comment: wouldn't it be best to check for the first if statement as the last statement in the for loop? It would prevent another iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
data = r'#33986=\r\n6 for User ID: 125091.'
data1 = re.search("(3\d{4}).....(\d)", data)
print(data1.group(1)+ data1.group(2))
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations & give an indication of what limitations & assumptions apply. If the Q has already been answered, report the post as a duplicate or write the link in the comments instead of re-answering to keep SO function as designed, ato upholds quality of SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
codes=[ c[1:][:-1] for c in re.findall('[^0-9]3[0-9]{5}[^0-9]', data)]
```